# ImageMagick overlay. Why does it change color?

Tags: imagemagick, overlay

I overlay the PNG image on background, also in PNG, but at the output I get that the color of the overlay image turned to gray.
How to make sure that the color does not change, but the image just overlays on the background?

```
convert.exe -composite -gravity center -geometry +0+120 -quality 100 "background.png" "3.png" "4.png"
```

3.png - Image overlay
4.png - Output image
Background.png - where to put 3.png

[all images this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzxCY.jpg)

Comment: If your background image is grayscale it could be the problem. You also need to link to the original images not a combined jpg so they can be used in tests.